# certbot webroot for multiple domain return only one certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, certbot

I'm trying to use `certbot certonly --webroot` to create cert for multiple domains but got only one certificate 
well, I went through this tutorial: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose) which works great for one domain.

so I tried to do the same for two domains(sub.domain.com domain.com)
nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://api:80;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }
}

server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://api:80;
            }

            location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                    allow all;
                    root /var/www/html;
            }
    }
```

then i used this command inside certbot container:

```
command: certonly --force-renewal --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d domain.com -d sub.domain.com --email some.email@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging
```

it's works but i got only one certificate (sub.domain.com).

```
certbot    | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot    | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
certbot    | Renewing an existing certificate
certbot    | IMPORTANT NOTES:
certbot    |  - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
certbot    |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem
certbot    |    Your key file has been saved at:
certbot    |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem
certbot    |    Your cert will expire on 2020-06-09. To obtain a new or tweaked
certbot    |    version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
certbot    |    again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
certbot    |    "certbot renew"
certbot exited with code 0
```

Comment: If you specify multiple `-d` values in one certbot command, it obtains one cert which covers all those domains; see https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#getting-certificates-and-choosing-plugins 2nd para and for your case https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot 2nd para . If you want separate certs use separate certbot commands.

Comment: thanks but what does it mean "one cert" which covers all? I'll use the same cert for different domains? which means configure nginx domain block ssl with the same ssl cert?

Comment: Yes. Or you can put the cert&key once, at the http level rather than the server level. If you let certbot do the config for you I _believe_ it does the former, but I don't currently have a setup I can easily confirm.